# A term to compare 2 stocks based on simultaneous trending and ranging characteristics

Tags: equities, statistics, correlation

There a 2 stocks called A and B.  We take a look at the daily chart of both stocks over the last 1 year. On 90% of the days A and B both trended or at least one of A or B trended.  On 10% of days both A and B ranged.

What term is used to describe a pair of stocks(or any asset) that exhibit the characteristics I described above(i.e given 2 stocks that at least one of those stocks on any given day, would trend. And this occurs more often than not).

Of course, it may look similar to correlation but what I mean by trend, does not mean both stocks must move in the same direction(unlike correlation).

Now the term must not necessarily be for stocks or financial markets. Like a term from statistics, for plotted data points(in financial markets called price charts) serves the purpose.